# Are all Boolean rings semi-artinian?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm basically only interested in the above question.  I have played with this a little bit and have not found an obvious way to prove it. However, I am not familiar with ways for proving something is semi-artinian in general (i.e. what seem to be set-theoretic methods, or discussions of the so-called socles).

If this is not generally true, is it likely to be true for the power set of the natural numbers?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that a semi-artinian $R$ ring is one such that every homomorphic image of $R$ in an $R$-module has a simple submodule.

Comment: The socle method is to prove that every nonzero $R$-module $M$ has a nonzero socle.  A socle is the sum of the minimal nonzero submodules of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's true for general Boolean rings.  However, for any set $S$, $\mathscr{P}(S)$, the power-set of $S$ (as a Boolean ring) is definitely semi-artinian.  Take some element $s\in S$, and look at the image of the submodule $\{\{s\},\emptyset\}$ under any $\mathscr{P}(S)$-module homomorphism.  Its image is clearly a minimal submodule.

Comment: If you're looking for a specific counterexample, I would guess you may want to start by looking at $R = S/I$ where $S = \prod_J \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $I = \bigoplus_J \mathbb{Z}/2$ for some infinite set $J$.  This is Boolean because $S$ is Boolean.